# Delete index of a nested element in mongo

Tags: php, mongodb

I have a collection in mongoDb. it is similar to the following.

```
array(
    '_id' => new MongoId("50b35d1217ce10ac1000000f")
    'Education' => 
      array (
        'content' => 
        array (
          '0' => 
          array (
            'Organization' => 'SUST',
            'Degree' => 'BSC',
            'Department' => '',
            'Location' => 'Dhaka',
            'Session' => '2 Years',
          ),
          '1' => 
          array (
            'Organization' => 'DU',
            'Degree' => 'BSC',
            'Department' => '',
            'Location' => 'Dhaka',
            'Session' => '2 Years',
          )    
        ),
        'sharing' => 'public',
      ),
)
```

I want to delete Education.content.1 from the collection.
So i used the

```
update(array('_id' => new MongoId('50b35d1217ce10ac1000000f')), array('$unset' => array('Education.content.1' => 1)));
```

As a result Education.content.1 becomes null. 
But I want Education.content.1 to be deleted not to be null.

Please help me if any one knows the solution. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$pull` after `$unset`:

```
update(array('_id' => new MongoId('50b35d1217ce10ac1000000f')), 
array('$unset' => array('Education.content.1' => 1)));
update(array('_id' => new MongoId('50b35d1217ce10ac1000000f')), 
array('$pull' => array('Education.content' => null)));
```